# I want to add a single quotes and coma on every word in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I want to add a single quotes and coma on every word in javascript, example bellow.

if my input values are

```
0000 
1111
2222
3333
4444
```

I required the above in this pattern.

```
'0000','1111','2222','3333','4444'
```

I have tried few example but got failures. my code bellow.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <textarea id="oid"></textarea>
  <br>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {

      var a = document.getElementById("oid").value;

      a1 = a.split(" ");


      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a1;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use `a1="'" + a.split(/\s+/).join("','") + "'";`

Comment: ok i wil check and tell

Comment: it is working thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure you are looking for this, but let me try based on what I understood. A string of numbers separated by whitespace listed as separated by commas and apostrophes.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var a = "111 333 222 4545 321";
  var string = "'" + a.split(" ").join("','") + "'";

  console.log(string);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = string;
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<div id="demo">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what your separator is you can do the following

```js
const textWithSpaces = "word1 word2 word3"
const textWithLineBreaks = "word1\nword2\nword3";

function doStuff(text, separator) {
  return text.split(separator).map(word => `'${word}'`).join(',');
}

console.log(doStuff(textWithSpaces, ' '));
console.log(doStuff(textWithLineBreaks, '\n'));

// Or with all kind of spaces

console.log(doStuff(textWithSpaces, /\s+/));
console.log(doStuff(textWithLineBreaks, /\s+/));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function test(){
        var str = document.getElementById("hello").value;
        var el = document.getElementById("hel");
        var arr = str.split(" ");
        var res = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            res += "'" + arr[i] + "', ";

        }
        el.innerHTML = res;
    }
```

```html
    <textarea name="" id="hello" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button onclick="test()">Click Me</button>

    <p id="hel"></p>
```